# Implement cookies banner for react and iubenda

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I have a React website. I want to show the cookie banner of [iubenda](https://www.iubenda.com/en/).
I'm using the following code which works but seems that React blocks the loading because the configurations which are used in the params of field "banner" are not respected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _iub = _iub || [];
    _iub.csConfiguration = {"askConsentAtCookiePolicyUpdate":true,"countryDetection":true,"enableLgpd":true,"enableUspr":true,"lgpdAppliesGlobally":false,"perPurposeConsent":true,"siteId":123456,"whitelabel":false,"cookiePolicyId":123456,"lang":"en", "banner":{ "acceptButtonCaptionColor":"#FFFFFF","acceptButtonColor":"#891703","acceptButtonDisplay":true,"backgroundColor":"#F9F9F8","closeButtonDisplay":false,"customizeButtonCaptionColor":"#000000","customizeButtonColor":"#E1E1E1","customizeButtonDisplay":true,"explicitWithdrawal":true,"fontSizeBody":"12px","listPurposes":true,"logo":null,"linksColor":"#891703","position":"bottom","rejectButtonCaptionColor":"#FFFFFF","rejectButtonColor":"#891703","rejectButtonDisplay":true,"theme":"asphalt-neutral","textColor":"#000000" }};

    (function(w, d) {
        var loader = function() {
            var s = d.createElement("script"),
                tag = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s.src = "//cdn.iubenda.com/cookie_solution/iubenda_cs.js";
            tag.parentNode.insertBefore(s, tag);
        };
        if (w.addEventListener) {
            w.addEventListener("load", loader, false);
        } else if (w.attachEvent) {
            w.attachEvent("onload", loader);
        } else {
            w.onload = loader;
        }
    })(window, document);

</script>
```